# Border is not working in Select Option CSS

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to change the border size and color of option . I tried but I am failed, Could someone please help me how to achieve my goals . Thanks

**Code**

```
select option {
 border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: What does your html tag look like?

Comment: it actually select and I want to change the border of options